# Laravel Meilisearch Scout - Select Does Not Exits

Tags: laravel, meilisearch

Using meilisearch scout, and want to get specific columns only on response. (To descrease the result size)

```
    $products = Product::search('blabla')
        ->select('title', 'id')
        ->paginate($paginate)
        ->load(['cover']);
```

But it returns error like that

```
Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::select does not exist
```

How can I pick specific columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to retrieve the data using **->paginate()** method, you must need to load the relations separately. For example:

```
$products = Product::search('blabla')
        ->query(function($query) { 
            $query->addSelect(['title', 'id']);  
        })
        ->paginate($paginate);
$products->load(['cover']);
```

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a Laravel search related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?